# jquery fadein not showing

Tags: jquery, html, function

Hey guys im trying to work out something with jquery and im a complet noob with javascript.

So lets first show you my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #circle { background: #f00; width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 100%; display: none;}
    </style>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    function showAllSlowly()
    {
        $('#circle').fadeIn('slow', function() {
            //complete
        });
        alert("Showing elements");
    };
    </script>
</head>

<body onLoad=showAllSlowly()>

<div id="circle"></div>
</body>
```

When i set the alert before the $('#circle') i can see it but not after so i guess my problem is within that function. And im using exactly the same one from the jquery website.

Any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: Wait, Which jQuery documentation suggests using `onload` attribute?

Comment: well none, i wanted to set it this way so it start displaying thing when its loaded..

Comment: jQuery has a handy [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method.

Comment: jquery documentation suggest to do it on a click function but i guess on load function is the same thing..?

Comment: use $(document).ready(function(){}) instead of onLoad because on load will be executed maybe before the elements are ready to be manipulated so the ready function will solve this and will execute the function just after the document is ready to be manipulated @Aenil :)

Comment: Instead of alert, you can use console.log()... When the alert box is up, the page is not rendering. But the javascript timer is still running and updating the css values. If you change slow to 5000 or something, you'll see when you click ok for alert, the circle has already started filling in.

Comment: Link for jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cQxGr/  hope its what you are  looking for.

Comment: Ok i finaly found out what was the problem after trying the document ready function with jquery... it wasnt loading my jquery from my scripts so nothing was working at all. I tryed the demo with the link to <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> instead of src="scripts/jquery..." and it worked. :|

I think it might have something to do with my apache server not configured to handle jquery or something... Cause i see it being downloaded in my browser but still nothing happen

Answer (score 2):

Or you can run the function as an immediately invoked Function on doc load.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/RUwXZ/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

(function showAllSlowly() {
        $('#circle').fadeIn('slow', function() {
            alert("complete");
        });
    })();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I cant seem to reproduce the error you're encountering. See this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/2SCRv/

Placing the alert before, after or within the #circle selector all work fine. Can you provide a jsFiddle example that reproduces the error?

Using onLoad is fine, although an even easier way is using the document ready function, which you are most likely already familiar with, and which achieves the same result.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#circle').fadeIn('slow', function() {
           alert("Showing elements");
    });            
});
```